# timeit.timeit variable importing in python

Tags: python, string, function, variables, timeit

I am trying to use `timeit.timeit()` in order to find how much time it takes to execute a specific line of code.
The problem is that this line includes variables and I need to import them somehow, so my question is how?
In order to be more clear, the code looks something like this:

```
def func():
    var1 = 'aaa'
    var2 = 'aab'
    t1 = timeit.timeit('var1==var2', 'from __main__ import ___', number = 10**4) #  here I'm missing what to put after the import
```

If I were trying to execute this code in `__main__` I would just import the variable directly with `'from __main__ import var1, var2'`
Any solution for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`timeit.Timer` [takes a callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) as well as a string to eval

> *Changed in version 2.6:* The stmt and setup parameters can now also
>   take objects that are callable without arguments. This will embed
>   calls to them in a timer function that will then be executed by
>   timeit(). Note that the timing overhead is a little larger in this
>   case because of the extra function calls.

(also see the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#l105), look for `elif hasattr(stmt, '__call__'):`).

Create a closure over the variables and pass it to timeit:

```
def func():
    var1 = 'aaa'
    var2 = 'aab'
    t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: var1 == var2, number = 10**4)
```

or equivalently:

```
def func():
    var1 = 'aaa'
    var2 = 'aab'
    def closure():
        return var1 == var2
    t1 = timeit.timeit(closure, number = 10**4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me inside `pdb` debugger and a class method. The solution that worked is to add the variables to `globals()`:

```
globals()['var1'] = var1
globals()['var2'] = var2
timeit.timeit(lambda: var1 == var2, number = 10**4)
```

Comment: I really like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer's solution of using `lambda` creates large overhead. Comparison with an alternative, using a setup string:

```
func1 117.3 ms
func2  39.0 ms
func1 116.8 ms
func2  41.6 ms
func1 117.2 ms
func2  35.8 ms
```

If you're trying to measure such a very fast code snippet, or compare the times of multiple, you'd better not overshadow their execution times with such a function call's large overhead and its variance.

Benchmark code that produced the above results ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LCsMgEEX3fsVsgrGEgAmFUsiXlCKmUSpUI8Ys@vXWOH1k09nIdbznoH/G@@z6kw8pGevnECEaq0wkZFIa9OpuvGZnAnkWDgNQKSXF2GEcMQYV1@De7RaP@iHtOMlzqQ65wX7Y7ovNRb@hKCU7xQ6/bf4q6IdNG0Rlh55DcYBxcCl/aNB5hQP0qPXBuFhvt60QTlolRFMWOLQ6tlyDXShUUJ7VLJe56hlL6QU)):

```
import timeit

def func1():
    s1 = 'aaa'
    s2 = 'aab'
    return timeit.timeit(lambda: s1 == s2)

def func2():
    setup = '''
s1 = 'aaa'
s2 = 'aab'
'''
    return timeit.timeit('s1 == s2', setup)

for func in [func1, func2] * 3:
    print(func.__name__,
          '%5.1f ms' % (func() * 1e3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `globals` argument takes a dictionary of variable names and values (i.e. a namespace). Simply pass global and local variables to the `globals` argument:

```py
def func():
    var1 = 'aaa'
    var2 = 'aab'
    t1 = timeit.timeit('var1 == var2', number=10**4, 
                       globals={**globals(), **locals()})
```

This will make available all the variables: global and local (including defined functions). In case there are some name collisions, then local variables will take over.